# Extract value from string with regex

Tags: regex, string, jmeter

I need to extract value (few numbers) from long text/string, I know exactly where that value must be, but there are few similar strings with similar values, but I only need extract that numbers from texts, who have certain word in it, but other values could be different.

Example:

```
Sample text for stackoverflow with value L12345 and some other word like RED.

Another text for example with value L54321 and one more BLUE word.

Last sample string L11122 and some other RED word.
```

In this example I must get the value L***** from strings, that contain word RED. I could use this:

```
Sample text for stackoverflow with value (.+?) and some other word like RED.
```

But it wont be right, because I need to xtract L11122 too, but strings are different, thats why it wont work.

Are they some method to do this? I work with Apache JMeter RegEX extractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right you want the pattern only on lines which have RED. If that's the case then you can use the below

```
(L\d+).* RED
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pI9oM4)